# cannot find osk.exe

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, process.start, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to launch the on screen keyboard with c#.  I need it to launch on a 32 bit machine.  I'm running win 10.  Thus far I've tried

```
Process.Start(@"%windir%\system32\osk.exe");

Process.Start(@"C:\Users\mxrac\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibilit\osk.exe");

Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Each time I get 
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

I've tried everything online and can get nothing to work.  I know the osk is there because I'm running it I just can't launch it via c#.
The machine that this has to run on is a 32 bit industrial PC I cannot configure the machine to run x64.

Comment: `Process.Start(@"%windir%\system32\osk.exe");` tried to use full path? something like `Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\osk.exe");` for instance.

Comment: tried it that didn't work either

Comment: there is a new folder called WinSxS in it there is osk.exe i found mine one in path "C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_7d1a4367d7272061\osk.exe" you can also use search option in windows folder to find other version of osk.exe . you cannot use system32 because the permission is restricted

Answer (score -1):

So this worked for me, but I'm on an x64 machine:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");
        proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(proc);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If I set Platform target to x86 it doesn't work, but if I set it to Any CPU and prefer 32-bit it does (under build properties).